# Nested IF and ISBLANK formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with a nested IF and ISBLANK formula. Here is the scenario:

There are three columns: A, B and C. All three are dates.

I want to retrieve the value of column A in column D (direct value). if Column A is blank, retrieve Column B value, if Column B is also blank retrieve Column C value.
Addition to this if column A has year `2015/2016` consider that cell as Blank and retrieve Column B/C.

How do I tackle this scenario?

Comment: Thanks Zack.. AS You have told Data doesn't contain a string of 2015/2016 . All columns  are in date format and I want to filter out based on Years. There are few dates which has years as 2100 and 2099, i want to consider those columns as blank.  may be as you have told (OR(ISBLANK(A3),A3>=DATE(2015,1,1))\\\ may work well..

Answer (score 1):

For your first bit:
`=IF(ISBLANK(A1),IF(ISBLANK(B1),C1,B1),A1)`

Then to add in the 2015/2016 check on A.  This:

`=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A3),AND(A3>=DATE(2015,1,1),A3<=DATE(2016,12,31))),IF(ISBLANK(B3),C3,B3),A3)`

Comment: Good breakdown - I believe the AND(...) statement could perhaps be simplified if @preethikrishna could elaborate on how the data is formatted. If the data is all dates from say 2010-2016, then the check could just be ///IF(OR(ISBLANK(A3),A3>=DATE(2015,1,1))\\\... - because the only items higher than 2015 would be 2015 or 2016. However the AND would be needed if the possible dates stretch before and after the 2015-2016 range.

Answer (score 0):

A different interpretation:

```
=1*TRIM(LEFT(IF(A1="2015/2016","",A1)&B1&C1,5))
```

Comment: I don't think he meant that column A would literally have the string "2015/2016" so much as he wants it to check if the date falls within one of those two years.

Comment: Thanks Zack.. AS You have told Data doesn't contain a string of 2015/2016 . All columns  are in date format and I want to filter out based on Years. There are few dates which has years as 2100 and 2099, i want to consider those columns as blank.  may be as you have told (OR(ISBLANK(A3),A3>=DATE(2015,1,1))\\\ may work well..