# Nesting IF and ISBLANK when appending information

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting to create an interactive grade book in excel to be able to estimate what my class score will be given how well I estimate to score on each assignment.

I have one sheet dedicated to entering each assignment score to show what my current grade in the class is, I'd like to make a second sheet where I can enter grades which are currently pending or missing; giving a new estimate of my class score without modifying the original grade book class score.

I had originally used the following function to append the information from the original grade book into the new one, but was unhappy with the results simply leaving "FALSE" for assignments which were already completed.

```
=IF(GradedAssignments[@Score]=0,GradedAssignments[@AssignmentTitle])
```

I'd like to create a function which simply appends the information into the next available row for each item that is a zero in the grade book, following a logic something like ...

- IF score for an assignment is for an assignment in the original grade book is equal to 0 at the same row as the missing work grade book being referenced,
- AND the row referenced in the missing work grade book is currently empty,
- THEN append the information from the original grade book to the missing work grade book to the row referenced.

But the function I wrote to do this doesn't seem to work and I'm not really familiar with what to do ...

```
=IF(AND(GradedAssignments[@Score]=0, ISBLANK(MissingAssignments[@UnfinishedAssignmentTitle])), GradedAssignments[@AssignmentTitle])
```

I've already looked at these two posts, and I'm still confused:
[Nesting IF and ISBLANK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698006/nesting-if-and-isblank)
[Nested IF and ISBLANK formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923346/nested-if-and-isblank-formula)

Comment: Are you aware that the IF() function allows you to provide a value for the FALSE outcome? `IF(a=0,b,c)` In my example, `c` is the value to be used if the expression provided as the first parameter is FALSE. Your example formulas do not have this third argument in the IF() function, which forces the IF() function to display FALSE on it's own. Sounds like you were expecting something else. If you want a blank result for the FALSE case, then you should provide a zero-length string for the third parameter... `IF(a=0,b,"")`

Comment: Hmm no that wouldn't work for what I need, if row 8 is a completed assignment the function would just leave the row blank instead of stating a false outcome. I'm looking for a function that would append the next missing item to the next empty row of the table. E.g., instead of: 1=A, 2=FALSE, 3=B, 4=C; you'd have: 1=A, 2=B, 3=C, 4=D etc.

Comment: following this line.. "in the grade book, following a logic something like ..." your formula DID do the first 2 steps. And it will perform step 3 if the conditions are met. But you need to also tell the formula what to do if the conditions is false.. you won't get " 1=A, 2=FALSE, 3=B, 4=C" if you put "" as the parameter.. you should get " 1=A, 2=, 3=B, 4=C" (empty @ 2), then you can use another formula to re-arrange the rows with values only.

Comment: @p._phidot_ Ohh I see so =IF(GradedAssignments[@Score]=0,GradedAssignments[@AssignmentTitle]) alone would do what I'd need done for the first bit, but I'd need an else statement which would reference the current cell plus one to get the next cell until the first condition is met, and then use that for AssignmentTitle ... I've no clue how to code for that.

Comment: Would you mind updating the question with some values in "GradedAssignments[@Score]" & "GradedAssignments[@AssignmentTitle]" + the sample output (for those data).. So that we can test out our solution..?

Comment: in reference to you last comment (skipping the blank row). This is an example that I propose : put 0 in B1, 'A' in A2, 'B' in A4, 'C' in A5, and 'E' in A7. Then in B2 put `=IF(A2="",A1,A1+1)` then drag downwards until B7. Then in D2 to D7, fill in 1 to 6 (individual numbers), in E2, put in `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(D2,$B$2:$B$7,0)),"")` and drag until E7. now you have the new list without blank

Comment: @p._phidot_ Can you please confirm that the example you provided is phrased correctly? I tested this idea, and I think I kinda see the logic behind the functions, but I'm still quite a noob at this. I've linked to my attempt at your hypothesis. [google docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XZJ91IUWwBhojXsBTPahMWpcowk0gsF03v4Sq1kkTRo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @p._phidot_ Further, here's a copy of the original workbook I was tinkering with, it might help you get a better idea of what I'm envisioning. [google docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DAn4o5wVjwhpWKOdR0hiX9YtPclb4gmXnRnVLLs2qlo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right.. I messed up the formula.. It should be `=IF(A2="",B1,B1+1)` & `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(C2,$B$2:$B$7,0)),"")`

Answer (score 0):

In MissingWork sheet, insert 3 column between A & B. Rename the column1 name (cell B2) to 0.

put in A2 :

```
=IF(AND(Gradebook!$C2=0,ISNUMBER(Gradebook!$C2)),Gradebook!$A2,"")
```

in B2 :

```
=IF([@[Unfinished Assignments]]="",B1,B1+1)
```

in C2 :

```
=ROW()-1
```

and in D2 :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([Unfinished Assignments],MATCH([@Column2],[0],0)),"")
```

That should do what you need. You may hide the 1st 3 columns for printing/display.

Idea : skip row loading if blank, by row numbering not counting if blank.